# Check whether all items of item2 inside a tuple(long,int) is unique

Tags: c#, tuples

Is there a way to use linq to check whether item2 from a tuple of long,int repeats itself more than once? I know it can be done on list. How to achieve the same in tuple? Can anyone help?

Comment: Why do you need it in the first place? I suspect there might be an easier solution. If you do want to do that, you can use reflection.

Comment: I need to check if item2 is unique if not use another tuple with three parameters to make it unique

Comment: @VladStryapko what should reflection have to do with this?

Comment: @RandRandom
I've understood the question as totally unrelated to lists and thought OP wants to enumerate through tuple's values and compare them dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var item2Set = new HashSet<int>();
bool allUnique = tupleList.All(t => item2Set.Add(t.Item2));
```

or

```
bool allUnique = !tupleList.GroupBy(t => t.Item2).Any(g => g.Count() > 1);
```

or

```
bool allUnique = tupleList.GroupBy(t => t.Item2).All(g => g.Count() == 1);
```

Comment: This works. I will mark as answer once time limit is reached. Thanks a lot.